# @OneToMany in Spring Data (channel with list of messages, eager fetching)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I would like to correctly add messages to a channel.

Channels without messages are added to a database properly:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Off-top",
    messageDTOs: [ ],
    participantDTOs: [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: "Szef",
        lastName: "Ceo",
        email: "szef.ceo@company.com",
    role: "ADMIN",
    manager: true
    }
}
```

But if I add one message to a channel I get a HTTP error 500 for GET: /channels.

I used `FetchType.EAGER` and relevant classes are as follows:

Message.java:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @OneToOne
    private Employee author;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime creationTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
    private Channel channel;

    public Message(String content, Employee author, Channel channel) {
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
        this.creationTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public boolean checkIfDataEquals(Message message) {
        return content.equals(message.getContent()) &&
                author.checkIfDataEquals(message.getAuthor()) &&
                channel.checkIfDataEquals(message.getChannel());
    }
}
```

Channel.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Channel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Message> messages;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Employee> participants;

    public Channel(String name, List<Employee> participants) {
        this.name = name;
        this.messages = new ArrayList<>();
        this.participants = participants;
    }

    public boolean checkIfDataEquals(Channel channel) {
        return name.equals(channel.getName()) &&
                compareParticipants(channel.getParticipants());
    }

    private boolean compareParticipants(List<Employee> participantList) {
        if (participantList.isEmpty())
            return true;
        for (Employee employee : participants) {
            if (participantList.stream().noneMatch(t -> t.checkIfDataEquals(employee)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is a problem with setting messagesDTOs in channelDTO because I get: `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null`

```
    at com.herokuapp.erpmesbackend.erpmesbackend.chat.ChannelDTO.<init>(ChannelDTO.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.herokuapp.erpmesbackend.erpmesbackend.chat.MessageDTO.<init>(MessageDTO.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
```

For classes:

MessageDTO.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MessageDTO {

    private long id;
    private String content;
    private EmployeeDTO authorDTO;
    private ChannelDTO channelDTO;
    private LocalDateTime creationTime;

    public MessageDTO(Message message) {
        this.id = message.getId();
        this.content = message.getContent();
        this.authorDTO = new EmployeeDTO(message.getAuthor());
        this.channelDTO = new ChannelDTO(message.getChannel()); // PROBLEMATIC LINE
        this.creationTime = message.getCreationTime();
    }

    public MessageDTO(String content, EmployeeDTO authorDTO, ChannelDTO channelDTO) {
        this.content = content;
        this.authorDTO = authorDTO;
        this.channelDTO = channelDTO;
    }

    public boolean checkIfDataEquals(MessageDTO messageDTO) {
        return content.equals(messageDTO.getContent()) &&
                authorDTO.checkIfDataEquals(messageDTO.getAuthorDTO()) &&
                channelDTO.checkIfDataEquals(messageDTO.getChannelDTO());
    }
}
```

ChannelDTO.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChannelDTO {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<MessageDTO> messageDTOs;
    private List<EmployeeDTO> participantDTOs;

    public ChannelDTO(Channel channel) {
        this.id = channel.getId();
        this.name = channel.getName();
        this.messageDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < channel.getMessages().size(); i++)
            messageDTOs.add(new MessageDTO(channel.getMessages().get(i)));  // PROBLEMATIC LINE
        this.participantDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        channel.getParticipants().forEach(participant -> this.participantDTOs.add(new EmployeeDTO(participant)));
    }

    public ChannelDTO(String name, List<EmployeeDTO> participantDTOs) {
        this.name = name;
        this.participantDTOs = participantDTOs;
    }

    public boolean checkIfDataEquals(ChannelDTO channelDTO) {
        return name.equals(channelDTO.getName()) &&
                compareParticipantDTOs(channelDTO.getParticipantDTOs());
    }

    private boolean compareMessageDTOs(List<MessageDTO> messageDTOList) {
        if (messageDTOList.isEmpty())
            return true;
        for (MessageDTO messageDTO: messageDTOs) {
            if (messageDTOList.stream().noneMatch(t -> t.checkIfDataEquals(messageDTO)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean compareParticipantDTOs(List<EmployeeDTO> participantDTOList) {
        if (participantDTOList.isEmpty())
            return true;
        for (EmployeeDTO participantDTO : participantDTOs) {
            if (participantDTOList.stream().noneMatch(t -> t.checkIfDataEquals(participantDTO)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

MessageController.java:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class MessageController {

    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;
    private final ChannelRepository channelRepository;
    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MessageController(MessageRepository messageRepository, ChannelRepository channelRepository,
                             EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
        this.channelRepository = channelRepository;
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/channels/{id}/messages")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public MessageDTO addOneMessage(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody MessageRequest messageRequest) {
        checkIfChannelExists(1L);

        String content = messageRequest.getContent();
        Channel channel = channelRepository.findById(id).get();

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        Employee author = employeeRepository.findByEmail(username).get();

        Message message = new Message(content, author, channel);
        messageRepository.save(message);
        return new MessageDTO(message);
    }

    private void checkIfChannelExists(Long id) {
        if (!channelRepository.findById(id).isPresent())
            throw new NotFoundException("Such channel doesn't exist!");
    }
}
```

ChannelController.java

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class ChannelController {

    private final ChannelRepository channelRepository;
    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ChannelController(ChannelRepository channelRepository, EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.channelRepository = channelRepository;
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/channels")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<ChannelDTO> getAllChannels() {
        List<Channel> channels = channelRepository.findAll();
        List<ChannelDTO> channelDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        channels.forEach(channel -> channelDTOs.add(new ChannelDTO(channel)));
        return channelDTOs;
    }

    @GetMapping("/channels/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ChannelDTO getOneChannel(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        checkIfChannelExists(id);
        return new ChannelDTO(channelRepository.findById(id).get());
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}/channels")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<ChannelDTO> getChannelsByParticipant(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        checkIfParticipantExists(id);

        if (!channelRepository.findByParticipantsId(id).isPresent())
            return new ArrayList<>();

        List<Channel> channels = channelRepository.findByParticipantsId(id).get();
        List<ChannelDTO> channelDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        channels.forEach(channel -> channelDTOs.add(new ChannelDTO(channel)));

        return channelDTOs;
    }

    @PostMapping("/channels")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ChannelDTO addOneChannel(@RequestBody ChannelRequest channelRequest) {
        String name = channelRequest.getName();

        checkIfParticipantListIsEmpty(channelRequest.getParticipantIds());
        List<Employee> participants = new ArrayList<>();
        channelRequest.getParticipantIds().forEach(this::checkIfParticipantExists);
        channelRequest.getParticipantIds().forEach(id -> participants.add(employeeRepository.findById(id).get()));

        Channel channel = new Channel(name, participants);
        channelRepository.save(channel);
        return new ChannelDTO(channel);
    }

    @PutMapping("/channels/{id}")
    public HttpStatus updateChannel(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody ChannelRequest channelRequest) {
        checkIfChannelExists(id);
        Channel channel = channelRepository.findById(id).get();

        channel.setName(channelRequest.getName());

        checkIfParticipantListIsEmpty(channelRequest.getParticipantIds());
        List<Employee> participants = new ArrayList<>();
        if (channelRequest.getParticipantIds() != null) {
            channelRequest.getParticipantIds().forEach(this::checkIfParticipantExists);
            channelRequest.getParticipantIds().forEach(index -> participants.add(employeeRepository.findById(index).get()));
        }
        channel.setParticipants(participants);

        channelRepository.save(channel);
        return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/channels/{id}")
    public HttpStatus removeChannel(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        checkIfChannelExists(id);
        channelRepository.delete(channelRepository.findById(id).get());
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }

    private void checkIfChannelExists(Long id) {
        if (!channelRepository.findById(id).isPresent())
            throw new NotFoundException("Such channel doesn't exist!");
    }

    private void checkIfParticipantExists(Long id) {
        if (!employeeRepository.findById(id).isPresent())
            throw new NotFoundException("At least one of the participant doesn't exist!");
    }

    private void checkIfParticipantListIsEmpty(List<Long> participantIds) {
        if (participantIds.isEmpty())
            throw new InvalidRequestException("List of participants can't be empty!");
    }
}
```

Could someone please assist?

Comment: using repositories in controller is not a good practice. I just scroll over your code and I suggest you to move repository from controller to service e.g. MessageService.class and annotate it with @Transactional

Comment: Thank you. I completely agree with you that services are needed, but in my opinion it should work without them too... So, I will try to add @Transacional

Comment: But, maybe anyone has idea how to solve the problem for current source code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have Bidirectional relation between channel and message,

- Message to channel is ManyToOne which is by default eager
- channel to message is OneToMany which is by default is lazy but you
  are enforcing eager fetching.

So you have bidirectional relation with two sides eager fetching which will cause hibernate to enter infinite loop of fetch each side from the other.

To solve this issue remove the eager fetch for messages inside channel

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense with infinite infinite loop... Well, I'll check it now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply once again, but when I try add one message by Postman (/channels/1/messages) or JUnit tests I get 500 error (fields are null).

Comment: @plkpiotr this is a different issue, one more advice if you can avoid having bidirectional relation in your DTO you should , otherwise you can start using some json filtering to fix the issue of circular dependency

Comment: @plkpiotr feel free to accept the answer if it solved the issue